# Reliable way of determining whether an user account requires a password?

Tags: c#, windows, user-accounts

I just wrote this code snippet for listing all local users and whether their account uses a password (credits to [Leniel Macaferi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750294/2668681))

```
var users = (from ManagementObject user in new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount").Get()
             where (uint)user["AccountType"] == UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT && (bool)user["LocalAccount"] && !(bool)user["Disabled"] && (bool)user["LocalAccount"] && !(bool)user["Lockout"]
             orderby (string)user["Name"] ascending
             select new { UserName = (string)user["Name"], PasswordRequired = (bool)user["PasswordRequired"] }).ToArray();

foreach (var user in users)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} (Requires password: {1})", user.UserName, user.PasswordRequired ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Using this code there was one specific user, whose `Win32_UserAccount.PasswordRequired` field was set to `false` even though this user is using a password. Changing his password via the System Control as well as setting an empty password and then resetting it didn't affect this flag, neither logging out and then in again nor rebooting refreshed this flag. On the other hand the User Account Control always says "Password protected" beneath this user even though `PasswordRequired` is set to `false`.

I actually `NetUserSetInfo`ed the flag to `true` by removing the `UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD` flag from the user's `USER_INFO_2.usri2_flags` field. This in turn changed the value of `Win32_UserAccount.PasswordRequired`, but it didn't affect my system's behavior. In fact I have to enter the password regardless of what this flag is saying, I can flip this flag all day long and it doesn't affect anything, so my question: **Is there a reliable way of determining whether one specific user is using a password?** (The solution preferable shouldn't require administrative privileges.)

Comment: The "password required" field is very old, dating back to DOS LAN manager.  I'm not sure what it did back then, but as far as I can tell it no longer does anything.  One way to check for a password is to attempt to log onto the account without one (via LogonUser) but I assume that would count as a failed logon attempt so repeated attempts could lock out the account.

Comment: Failed logon attempts fall under the Account Lockout Policies, which are user specific. Anyway, this solution works pretty well on my machine, thank you :)