# Removing from listbox an unknown value

Tags: c#

I've listed all directories from C:\Users\ to a listbox.

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users\\", "*" , SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
```

All Users in Windows have the folder \\AppData\\ but I don't want to mess with these folders because they have important files for windows, assuming a computer's guy using my software have 2 or more windows accounts, all these have \\AppData\\ folder, with first user I used to do:

```
listbox1.items.remove("C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\AppData\\")
```

but I don't know the others users name, there is any way to remove all AppData folders in listbox without knowing the username?

Comment: why you not saving this data in registers ?

Comment: Did you consider getting a list of subfolders from the directory (path)? Maybe that would help? :)

Comment: I agree with sometowngeek, that will solve your problem

Comment: " I don't want to mess with these folders because they have importante files for windows" Are your users aware of your not seeming to have a problem "messing" with other data in their `Users` folders?

Comment: I think `System.Manegment` could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749537/how-can-i-get-a-list-local-windows-users-only-the-users-that-appear-in-the-wind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the user names  using this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username : {0}", envVar["Name"]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    // end of class
}
```

you might need to add reference  for `System.Management`

Comment: From msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx `Note  Because both the Name and Domain are key properties, enumerating Win32_UserAccount on a large network can negatively affect performance. Calling GetObject or querying for a specific instance has less impact.` Makes the answer not false. Just want to make sure, that the performance could be bad.

Comment: Thank you, Its worked, and I don't need time or performance, also thank you Ben.