# How do I implement an if statement for true or false? with the outcome of a PowerShell command

Tags: c#, powershell, if-statement, process

*The title might be a bit confusing because I don't know how to ask something like this if someone knows a better title let me know.*

So what i did here is made a application that will give me all the users that are enabled. The problem is I don't know how i can get that data and use it further in my code. because I want to delete all the inactive ones but keep the active ones and with the active ones I will go on with my project.

So, for short, the question is how do I use/get the outcome of the command and go further with my application?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetUserList();
}

public static string GetUserList()
{
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    
    foreach (ManagementObject User in searcher.Get())
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = $@"powershell ";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"Get-LocalUser -Name {(string)User["Name"]} | Where-Object Enabled";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
    }
    
   return null;
}
```

[This is one of the outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTRUF.png)

If anyone knows a better way to do this or knows how to answer my question please let me know.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @mklement0.

```
(Get-LocalUser -Name {(string)User["Name"]}).Enabled
```

With this i can get a True or False out of every user.

Comment: `GetUserList()` returns a single string - what should the contents of that string be? The table output from your screenshot? A comma-separated list of usernames?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750294/40256) help you?. I feel that with a little bit of tweaking it will do what you want.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen eventually i want to return all the active users

Comment: @mklement0 i have tried using PowerShell SDK but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @mklement0 That's what i am looking for thank you an the others for helping.

I don't know how to close this question but its closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you're better off using an in-process solution based on the [PowerShell SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart).
Apart from being faster, it also allows you to get back *typed data* (rather than strings via stdout).

With your current approach, which requires creating a PowerShell *child process* in each iteration, use the following to get a (stringified) Boolean value as output for each user, i.e., `"True"` or `"False"`, which indicates whether that user is enabled or not.

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"(Get-LocalUser -Name {(string)User[""Name""]}).Enabled"
```